# Div with both floating element and vertically centered dynamic content inside

Tags: css

That's a famous problem but still I could not find a solution to it. What I want to achieve is this:

```
<div>
  <div class="buttons" style="float: right">BUTTONS</div>
  .... random content of any length/size here vertically centered
</div>
```

Now, to clarify the problem - it would work fine if the content is higher than the floating buttons, but sometimes it's not - one line of text and tall buttons.

The existing solutions do not work because for example:

- I need a floating element so I can't use flex for container
- The main content should dictate the container height so I cannot make it position: absolute (well, actually both content and floating should dictate the height)
- I can't use fixed height

Here are few things that I tried - you can see that it doesn't really work - text overlaps floating, container size not increased with content, etc. The first one serves as an example that is **almost** what I need - except that it's not centered vertically, that's the missing part.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.float {
  float: right; 
  background: green;
}

#test1 {
  border: 1px solid red; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  display: table-cell; 
  width: 300px;
}

.test2 {
  position: relative; 
  border: 1px solid red; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  display: table-cell; 
  width: 300px;
}

.text {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 50%; 
  left: 0; 
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="test1">
    <div class="float">Float Float</div>
    <div>When content is large it should dictate the height and wrap to fill the available space even horizontally - which is why float is needed</div>
  </div>

  <div id="test1">
    <div class="float">Float<br/>Float<br/>Float</div>
    <div>But if content is short and float big - content is not centered</div>
  </div>

  <div class="test2">
    <div class="float">Float<br/>Float<br/>Float</div>
    <div class="text">We can center it e.g. with absolute</div>
  </div>

  <div class="test2">
    <div class="float">Float<br/>Float<br/>Float</div>
    <div class="text">But the same markup will not quite work if the content is longer - it overlaps floating </div>
  </div>

  <div class="test2">
    <div class="float">Float</div>
    <div class="text">And if floating height is not enough the content will overflow <br/>Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In real app that would be something like a content card but with floating actions in the top right corner (kind of window buttons) - actions can be buttons, images, etc - so both content and floating actions have dynamic unknown size.

Comment: Why do you need a floated element? if no CSS solution is possible because of your restraints, you might need to use JS to achieve your layout: calculate all values (height/ width, whatever you need) based on other elements and set them to the respective item.

Comment: Calculating height in js would be hard because I would need to do that on every container size change (that can happen not only with window change but also with splitter change, etc). I need floating element because, well, that's the requirements that I have. Basically I think this is to save screen space as the text then can wrap and flow below them.

Comment: it's not clear what you want, can you mockup the desired result? I don't get how you want to float and center at the same time

Comment: But "this is not possible" is a valid answer, too, I guess...

Comment: *The first one serves as an example that is almost what I need - except that it's not centered vertically, that's the missing part.* --> what is not centred? the float element?

Comment: @TemaniAfif - added a sample (the second one now) of that I want, though basically it's what I already had - I just made the content line shorter so that it's clear that it's centered. Unfortunately if the content text is bigger it becomes the other existing examples - overlapping the floating buttons.

Comment: @TemaniAfif - no, the content should be centered vertically. The floating is fine to be in the top right corner.

Comment: in the first one, the content is defining the height so centered relatively to what?

Comment: @TemaniAfif - centered relatively to the height of the container that is defined by the floating element if its height is bigger than the content's height (as I said "both content and floating should dictate the height").

Comment: If first example had just one line - it would not be centered (which is needed). I added long wrapping text to the first example to show why floating is needed - so that the long content wraps and fills the available space.

Comment: Instead of writing 100 comments here can you update the question itself with more details? Looks like multiple people are confused on what you actually want to achieve. Maybe add some pictures to display the desired result?

Comment: I just answer the questions. But OK I tried now to add meaningful text to the examples that tell the story of what's needed and what are the problems.

Comment: I guess you have to calculate width/height for each element with JS and set position also via JS. Can be not good on performance if there are many of these elements. Or talk to your designer if you can get a modern design without this requirement, maybe something you can do with flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want like this

```css
      .container .box {
        width: 500px;
        display: table;
      
    }

        .container .box .box-row {
            display: table-row;
            width:100%;
        }

        .container .box .box-cell {
            display: table-cell;
            border: 1px solid black;
            vertical-align: middle;
            overflow-wrap: anywhere;
        }
    .bgGreen {
        background: green;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-row">
            <div class="box-cell box1">
                When content is large it should dictate the height and wrap to fill the available space - which is why float is needed
            </div>
            <div class="box-cell box2 bgGreen">
                floatttttttttttttttttttttttttttt
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="box-row">
            <div class="box-cell box1">
                But if content is short and float big - content is not centered
            </div>
            <div class="box-cell box2 bgGreen">
                float<br />float<br/>float
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The requirement is to have the float so that when content is large it wraps to fill the available space. This is why I mentioned in the question that flex is not an option - there's no way for the content to wrap **under** the (green) actions. What you have is just a simple two-column flex box. I.e. with your setup it's not possible to achieve the first example from my examples.

Comment: without setting the width or flex basis it will not work. if the left box content will small in size then right div will move to left side. because left div width is auto as per content length.

Comment: Setting width of that? I do set width of the container. I guess you can set any width as long as the left content wrap under the floating right box.

Comment: The second line of the left text should go **below** / **under** the green text - this is what float does. If left text content has 100 lines, the 98 last lines should occupy full container width **under** green float text. You still have a simple two-column setup.